# Calculating the conditional expectation of a Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $B$ be a BM, $t\in (0,1)$. Calculate $E(B_t|B_1)$.

There is a hint: If we have a sequence of i.i.d. variables $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ and the first moment of $X_1$ exists, then for $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, this a.s. holds: $E[X_i|S_n] = E[X_j|S_n]$ for all $1 ≤ i, j ≤ n.$

I started wtih $B_1 = \sum_{i=1}^nB_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}$ for $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=1$.

So now we can write $E(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}|B_1)=E(B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}|B_1)$. If I would be able to express $E(B_{t_i}|B_1)$ with some known quantities I would be done, but I do not know how to proceed.

Is the way I started correct (or useful) or is there a better way? In both ways, how can I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Rational Times. Let $t=p/q$ where $p,q\in\mathbb N$. Then $E(B_{\frac{p}{q}}|B_1)=pE(B_{\frac{1}{q}}|B_1)$. Also, $B_1=E(B_{\frac{q}{q}}|B_1)=qE(B_{\frac{1}{q}}|B_1)$. Thus $E(B_{\frac{p}{q}}|B_1)=\frac{p}{q}B_1$; i.e., if $t$ is rational, $E(B_t|B_1)=tB_1$.

Step 2: Arbitrary Times. Let $t_n$ be rational numbers s.t. $t_n\rightarrow t$. Then
\begin{align}
E\left[\left(E(B_{t_n}|B_1)-E(B_t|B_1)\right)^2\right]
&= E\left[\left(
  E(B_{t_n}-B_t|B_1)
\right)^2\right]\\
&\le 
E\left[
  E((B_{t_n}-B_t)^2|B_1)
\right]\rightarrow 0,
\end{align}
and accordingly we have a subsequence $E(B_{t_{n_k}}|B_1)$ converging a.s. to $E(B_t|B_1)$. This gives us $E(B_t|B_1)=tB_1$ a.s. for arbitrary $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Does this use the hint provided, as I don't see it? Not that it has to, just wondering.

Comment: You're welcome. In the first line, $E(B_{\frac{p}{q}}|B_1)$ equals $pE(B_{\frac{1}{q}}|B_1)$ by the hint because $B_{\frac{p}{q}}=B_{\frac{1}{q}}+(B_{\frac{2}{q}}-B_{\frac{1}{q}})+\ldots$ and the increments are i.i.d. Same goes for the other claim $E(B_{\frac{q}{q}}|B_1)=qE(B_{\frac{1}{q}}|B_1)$.